# Como concateno uma string sem usar as funções da biblioteca string?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

```
#include <stdio.h>

void concatenar (char str1, char str2){
    int c, a;

    for(c=0; str1[c]!='0'; c++)

    for(a=0; str2[a]!='0'; a++){
        str1[c]=str2[a];
    }
    return str1;
}
int main (void){
    char str1[10], str2[10];

    printf("Digite uma palavra: ");
    gets (str1);
    printf("Outra palavara: ");
    gets(str2);

    printf(void ("%s", str1));

    puts(concatenar(str1, str2));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bem vinda ao SOpt Camilla! tente, além de postar o código, especificar o problema que está tendo. dê uma olhada nesse tópico e entenda [como criar um exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1186/138733)

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz algumas correções no seu código, testei e estava funcionando, mas antes algumas observações:

Em C++, caso se trate realmente de C++ e não C89 como está parecendo, seria preferível utilizar uma `std::string` (onde a concatenção pode ser feita com o operador +).

E definitivamente não é aconselhável a utilização da função `gets()`, pois ela é insegura, já que não verifica os limites do array, tendo sido inclusiva removida no C11.

Dito isso, vamos ao código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* concatenar (char str1[], char str2[]){

   int c, a;
   for(c = 0; str1[c] != '\0'; c++){}

   for(a = 0; str2[a] != '\0'; a++, c++){
      str1[c] = str2[a];
   }

   str1[c] = '\0';

   return str1;
}


int main (){

   char str1[100], str2[100];

   printf("Digite uma palavra: ");
   gets (str1);

   printf("Outra palavra: ");
   gets(str2);

   puts(concatenar(str1, str2));
   return 0;
}
```